# Quit existing driver browser before executing next script

Tags: selenium

I have a Silenium script set up on a loop to fuzz input fields on an webapp. Occasionally, some of the divs fail to load in which causes the script to fail because it can't find the div. I would like to just close the entire browser and just start the next loop iteration with a new `driver.get(url)`. Since the original driver is still connected to the first browser window, I tried adding `driver.quit(url)` to the beginning of my script like below but for some reason when I run it, it just opens the browser first and then closes it afterwards. Is there a reason why `driver.get(url)` is executing before `driver.quit(url)`?

```
def run_script(driver):
    driver.quit(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Maybe because in the first iteration when you trying to `driver.quit(url)` before you opened it by `driver.get(url)` it just does nothing while from the second iteration and so on it quits the previously opened page and opens again after the `time.sleep(5)`?

Comment: Yep. It seems like that was the issue. I put the `driver.quit(url)` into it's own if statement and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: If so please accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the first iteration when you trying to `driver.quit(url)` before you opened it by `driver.get(url)` it just does nothing while from the second iteration and so on it quits the previously opened page and opens again after the `time.sleep(5)`